# How can I make babel generating polyfills like `__createClass` just a one time for multiple files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs

My project containing many ES6 files and all of these are containing at least one class. 
`__createClass`,`__interopRequireDefault` and `__classCallback` polyfilling function are generated for each files. 
I would concat them with browserify after that, and I guess it is too redundant to keep them for all of files.
I think I can inject polyfilling functions during bundling task.

When I use typescript, I can specify `--noEmitHelpers` options not to generate such codes during compiling task. Is there something way to do that with babel?

Comment: I do not know how to do this with `browserify`, but in `webpack` you could create a "common chunk" (e.g. a vendor.js file) that would be the single source for polyfills like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`. It does exactly what you're looking for. Check out the [docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/).

> This is where the transform-runtime plugin comes in: all of the helpers will reference the module babel-runtime to avoid duplication across your compiled output. The runtime will be compiled into your build.

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime 
$ npm install --save babel-runtime
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```